# Converting 1D radial profil to 2D image

Tags: python, image, python-2.7

How can I convert 1D vector f(r) to an image, with symmetrical revolution. I'm using python 2.7.

What I want to do with a figure. I want the image on right with a vector on left:

[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a distance matrix with zero at it's center and just plot that as argument to any function you wish:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def centeredDistanceMatrix(n):
    # make sure n is odd
    x,y = np.meshgrid(range(n),range(n))
    return np.sqrt((x-(n/2)+1)**2+(y-(n/2)+1)**2)

def function(d):
    return np.log(d) # or any function you might have

d = centeredDistanceMatrix(101)
f = function(d)
plt.plot(np.arange(51),function(np.arange(51)))
plt.show()
plt.imshow(f.T,origin='lower',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: Log of numbers]

, and:

[image: 2D log of numbers]

**EDIT:** for arbitrary data.

You can use `interp1D` to pass your vector to a function in order to give pixel values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def centeredDistanceMatrix(n):
    # make sure n is odd
    x,y = np.meshgrid(range(n),range(n))
    return np.sqrt((x-(n/2)+1)**2+(y-(n/2)+1)**2)

def function(d):
    return np.log(d) # or any funciton you might have

def arbitraryfunction(d,y,n):
    x = np.arange(n) 
    f = interp1d(x, y)
    return f(d.flat).reshape(d.shape)

n = 101
d = centeredDistanceMatrix(n)
y = np.random.randint(0,100,n) # this can be your vector
f = arbitraryfunction(d,y,n)
plt.plot(np.arange(101),arbitraryfunction(np.arange(n),y,n))
plt.show()
plt.imshow(f.T,origin='lower',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

, the result is this:

[image: arbitrary 1D data]

, and this:

[image: revolution of arbitrary data]

Comment: Ok, but if I don't have a function but just a vector with arbitrary profil?

Comment: For the sake of my eyesight and suffering of several scientist: could you use another colormap other than jet? viridis for example (its the default in the last version of matplotlib)! +1 for this fantastic answer, of course

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following program if the function is known in terms of 'r'.

```
from pylab import*
x=linspace(-10,10,200)
y=linspace(-10,10,200)
xx,yy=meshgrid(x,y)
z=sin((xx**2.0+yy**2.0)**0.5)
imshow(z)
show()
```

In this program I have plotted the 2D revolution of the function f(r)=sin(r).

Since the meshgrid is in x-y coordinates and f is a function of 'r', we have to change coordinate system (from polar to cartesian)

```
r= ((x**2 + y**2 ) **0.5)
```

So  f(r) = sin(r)  becomes

```
f(x,y)=sin( ((x**2 + y**2 ) **0.5) )
```

For plotting both figures in one frame, they can be added as subplots to the main frame.

```
from pylab import*

fig = figure()
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

r=linspace(0,10,200)
fr=sin(r)
sub1.plot(r,fr)

x=linspace(-10,10,200)
y=linspace(-10,10,200)
xx,yy=meshgrid(x,y)
z=sin((xx**2.0+yy**2.0)**0.5)
sub2.imshow(z)

sub1.set_title('1D')
sub2.set_title('2D')

show()
```

The sizes of the subplots can be adjusted manually from the 'Configure subplots' widget at the bottom of the window.

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luOIJ.png)

[image]